Lightning input validation blocking the button click
I have a lightning input configured like below
 <lightning-input
            type="text"
            label="Phone Number"
            name="Phone Number"
            value={phoneNumber}
            class="phone"
            message-when-pattern-mismatch={phoneValidationError}
            pattern={phonePattern}
            onchange={handleNumberChange}
            maxlength="20"
            disabled={isDisabled}
          ></lightning-input>

When I enter some value which does not match the pattern of this input and directly click a button which is a lightning button, the button click is not registered/triggered. Instead the pattern check happens and the input error is displayed. So the blur event whihc fires the validation of this input blocks the click event of the button. If I click  the button second time the click will be triggered.
How do I resolve this?
